# Can make graphql query to be strongly types with typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

I'm using typescript and graphql and every time I want to send request to my graphql I need to write a query.

My question is there is anyway to use type/interface to create the query?

for example take a look at this interface:

```
interface Document {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  author: {
    name: string;
  }
}
```

The graphql query for this is

```
query document {
  id
  name
  author {
    name
  }
}
```

and I use axois to get the data:

```
const data = await axios.get("/graphql", { query });
```

Is there easy way to get the data using strongly typed? something like:

```
const data = await axois.get('/graphql', { fields: ['id', 'name', 'author.name'] })
```

And typescript will throw an error if some string from fields doesn't include in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

`axios.get` can take a generic which will provide the types on the return type. An example should make it clear. Using your code above

```
//                             vvvvvvvv==> your expected return data
const result = await axios.get<Document>("/graphql", { query });

// data will be strongly typed (but NOT checked)
result.data.id; // => string
result.data.author.name; // => string
```

For more info check axios' `index.d.ts` file.